# How to get system user in ant (within eclipse)?

Tags: java, eclipse, ant

How can I access the name of the system user (which eclipse also uses for the javadoc 
author tag) in my ant build file?

I'm trying to show some information about the current program version in my java application.
I decided to use [jreleaseinfo](http://jreleaseinfo.sourceforge.net/) which passes variables from my ant build script to my java classes (to show them in a window). With [svnant](http://subclipse.tigris.org/svnant.html) I'm even capable of accessing the latest revision number and build date from svn within my build.xml.

Now: The last thing I need is to show who made that build!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This will work anywhere. It uses the java system property **user.name**.

```
<property environment="env" />
<echo message="user: ${user.name}" />
```

Comment: yes - sometimes it can be that easy...
I just found it myself. All the system-variables you can use are explained here: http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.3/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getProperties()

Answer (score 3):

`user.name` can be used:

```
<echo>User is: ${user.name}</echo>
```

Results in:

```
[echo] User is: coobird
```